# Stacking circles

Tags: recreational-mathematics, circles, packing-problem

When I tried to stack 21 circles of radii $(30, 31, 32... 50)$ on top of each other in a tube (ID of $100$ wide), I thought they would reach the same height regardless of the order, however I was wrong. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1ypj5avxzq) I tried out three different arrangements of what order to stack the circles, from largest to smallest, alternating largest and smallest, and alternating from middle to largest and working smaller. I cannot come to a clear conclusion of which way would stack all of the circles in the lowest height. Does anyone have any idea of what method of stacking would give the lowest height?

Comment: When the tube was small enough that no two circles would fit next to each other, I proved that the optimal packing was to start with the smallest one, put the next two smaller on either side, and continue, so it would be $50 \dots 38,36,32,30,31,33,35 \dots 49$ I don't remember enough to be sure it works when you can have circles next to each other.

Comment: This is a superb problem, but it definitely deserves a better description.

Comment: I tried to answer a problem which is similar to yours and got an answer not quite the  same as yours. FYI: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97842/project-euler-question-222/618476#618476